# Change Facebook Default Page from Info to Wall

Tags: facebook

My default profile page on facebook links to the "Info" page. How do you change the default landing page to show the "Wall" tab.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think you can choose the default profile page tab yourself. However, friends should automatically see the **Wall** tab as the default. All others should automatically see the **Info** tab as the default.